# Eclipse Add and remove... shortcut

Tags: eclipse

I need to know a shortcut to show the `Add and remove...` window that normally appears when someone press right click on a server in the `Servers` view

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any keyboard shortcut for that; seems to be an oversight by the WTP plugins.